# Are the 4 LCD screws to fix the LCD replacement in an iPad critical?

Tags: hardware, ipad, repair

I just successfully replaced the front glass of my 3th Gen iPad WiFi, but when I cleaned up my desk, I found out I forget to use the 4 LCD screws:

[image]

Is it worth it working another hour to open up the iPad again and place those screws in place? Or are the adhesives strong enough to keep the LCD in place?

Comment: It happened the same thing to me, what did you do finally? It was so critical? I really don't want to disassembly it again, I don't want to crack the screen... Thank you!

Comment: If they weren't strictly necessary, Apple wouldn't put them there...

Comment: @Jordi, I did reassemble the iPad... The answer of bmike convinced me to do so...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go back in unless you are worried you will break it the second entry.

Adhesives won't hold under vibration and shock like a screw will and the screw pressure is what helps set the adhesive in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I realize it may be better to reopen the unit and replace the screws, but I still have the first iPad 2 I replaced the screen on and I completely misplaced my LCD screws. I just decided to put pressure on the back of the unit to hold the adhesive to both the covered glass and unit.

I've found over the last few years in the dusty environment of my farming community that it works just great anywhere. However I can understand that you may not want the LCD placing any pressure on the backside of the new digitizer.

If you are proficient at getting back in the unit I'd try to put them where they belong but mine works just great the way it is without the corner support screws.

Answer (score -1):

The might be important for keeping it from falling apart with rough use, but if the adhesive is good, you should be OK.  I did this once and I put a duck tape on the edge of my Ipad just to make sure the digitizer and LCD wouldn't come off.  I didn't heat the adhesive because I didn't want to spend another hour or two prying off tiny shards of glass the next time the screen broke.  The duck tape might not look great to some people, but it gave it a little extra padding and worked well until I broke the screen again.  I am in the process of replacing the screen for the second time and it's a lot easier to cut the duck tape than it is to work with that nasty adhesive.

Comment: Duck tape... Really? Do you even care about long-term reparations? Besides the fact it's a very bad adhesive for such materials, it also increases the thickness of the screen... I'm pretty sure the duck tape causes the screen cracking again. You should learn to use some decent glue and adhesive

Comment: Duck tape on the outside, not the inside!

Comment: And there's also just enough stickiness from the adhesive inside to help keep things sealed and locked together.